# Are these acceptable temperatures for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature, hp-elitebook, speedfan

I just installed SpeedFan 4.0 since my laptop's fan seems to be continually running at a high speed.  It reports these numbers:

GPU: 74C
Temp1 (ACPI): 75C
Temp2 (ACPI): 95C
Core 0: 89C
Core 1: 89C

These seem awfully high to me, should I be concerned?  This is an HP EliteBook 8730w with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Extreme CPU X9100 @ 3.06GHz and nVidia Quadro FX 3700M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems normal. Intel chips can run that hot and sometimes hotter. Some high power gpu's get hotter than that in desktop computers.
You can boil water on the new Macbook pro I7 chips.

Laptops run hot man.

You can look online for the manufacturers specified running temperatures.

Which CPU and GPU does your model have

[Here is the spec sheet from HP.](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3740645-3955549-3784202.html) Then Google the chips running temperature and make sure you are in spec.

Comment: This is an HP EliteBook 8730w with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Extreme CPU X9100 @ 3.06GHz and nVidia Quadro FX 3700M.

Comment: you are good man. Don't worry. Your laptop is smart enough to shut itself down if it gets to hot. Enjoy that beast!